# Phpunit grabbing Doctrine2 configuration from unknown place

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, phpunit

I am using ZF2 + Doctrine2 + PHPUNIT, when setting up Phpunit, it works fine for a basic test, however as soon as I try to run a test that invokes Doctrine2, I get:

```
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'username'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

But, I have never specified "username" nor "localhost" nor any sort of password. In-fact, my application runs perfectly fine, and the configuration I have specifies completely different settings.

So where is PHPUnit getting those settings and how to fix it?

My global.php:

```
'doctrine' => array(
    'connection' => array(
        'orm_default' => array(
            'driverClass' => 'Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOMySql\Driver',
            'params' => array(
                'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                'port' => '3306',
                'user' => 'sbapp',
                'password' => 'myp@ss',
                'dbname' => 'root'
            )
        )
    ),
```

The Test:

```
class ApplicationControllerTest extends AbstractHttpControllerTestCase
{
    protected $traceError = true;

    public function setUp()
    {
        $this->setApplicationConfig(
            include '../../../config/application.config.php'
        );

        parent::setUp();
    }

    public function testAuthActionCanBeAccessed()
    {
        $postData = new \stdClass();
        $postData->username = "someAppUser";
        $postData->password = "12345";
        $postData = json_decode(json_encode($postData),true);

        $this->dispatch('/auth', 'POST', $postData);

        $response = $this->getResponse();

        $this->assertResponseStatusCode(200);
        $this->assertActionName('auth');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The relative paths used within the config on setUp when done incorrectly can seriously affect the loading of entities and so on. So I was chasing around the right path.. when calling phpunit from root..or from vendor..or from within the test folder, etc..

Solution:

Call it from project root, and leave the routes exactly as the main project are.